# How can I reset Visual Studio's publishing configuration to default?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I am just a hobbyist programmer so I am sorry if I am asking a question I should know the answer to. I searched for an answer, but never found it, so I thought I would join and post a question here.

I have some VB 2010 Express code I have written that I wished to deploy from my web page. I used Visual Studio's ClickOnce publishing system and was pleased with the results.

After a couple of versions published I went into the publisher's configuration manager to explore the options.

That was my, uhhh, mistake. I changed many things that I thought would make things nicer for the deployment but screwed up something because now all versions, even previously working versions no longer deploy correctly. If you click for a download and installation, the install starts but the installer complains that there is an error it wants to report to Microsoft.

Is there some way to reset the publish configuration back to it's starting values?
I am running VB on XP with Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Comment: Do you have a backup of the project file you can revert to? It is the ProjectName.vbproj file. It contains all the publish settings.

Comment: if you don't have  a backup ! Then you can also try... create a new project and then compare what you have changed in the not working project.

Comment: Hi Mike, I've edited the salutations & signature out of the beginning and end of your answer. Whilst the politeness is appreciated, we generally edit such things out of posts to concentrate them entirely on the issue at hand. Your post is already signed by your user information anyway. And welcome to the site!

Comment: Creator, pSattele: If either of you change yourcomments to "Answers" I would be happy to accept. Both are the same answer from different points of view.

Comment: @Mike-WM1KE - You can yourself frame a answer by taking cues from the comments and providing more details on how you actually fixed it. 2 days later, you can accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reset the Publish settings for my actual project by comparing the content of the project files for two sample projects, one with publishing and the other one without and identifying which entries were added. I used the FC DOS command to output the differences to a text file (the file extensions were .csproj since mine was a C# project):

```
fc publish_project.csproj non_publish_project.csproj > diff.txt
```

I examined diff.txt and found what changed. Deleting the following entries from the real project file will reset the Publish option (**do a backup first!**):

```
    <IsWebBootstrapper>true</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <PublishUrl>ftp://ftpserver.com/</PublishUrl>
    <Install>false</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Web</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>true</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <InstallUrl>http://www.myproduct.net/project1/downloads/</InstallUrl>
    <CreateWebPageOnPublish>true</CreateWebPageOnPublish>
    <WebPage>publish.htm</WebPage>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>

    ...

      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetZone>LocalIntranet</TargetZone>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
      </PropertyGroup>
    ...

      <ItemGroup>
        <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
          <Visible>False</Visible>
          <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
          <Install>false</Install>
        </BootstrapperPackage>
        <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
          <Visible>False</Visible>
          <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
          <Install>true</Install>
        </BootstrapperPackage>
        <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1">
          <Visible>False</Visible>
          <ProductName>Windows Installer 3.1</ProductName>
          <Install>true</Install>
        </BootstrapperPackage>
      </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying the file ProjectName.vbproj from a very previous version took care of my problem.
I would presume that the other suggestion, creating a new project and copying it's file, should have the same result. Especially if you do not have previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish, it creates a profile with all the configuration settings.
So, you just have to delete that profile.
Click on "**Delete**" and it should be reseted.